# Why BinaryFormatter silently breaks process?

Tags: c#, binaryformatter

I'm trying to serialize object with following procedure:

```
    public static byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null)
            return null;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

I've got break point on `bf.Serialize(ms, obj);` and I can check that my object is fine there but when I go to the next step it just breaks operation without any errors or saying anything. I even don't know how should I debug it for now. Any ideas?

Comment: What is your object ? Perhaps there is some property you may need to set as nonserializable.

Comment: `Ctrl+alt+e` and check all exceptions, maybe you unchecked some and exception is silent :)

Comment: @wudzik thanks, now I see "is not marked as serializable."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case it needs the serializable attribute on the class like this...

```
[Serializable]
public class YourClass
```